# How do I access an alias declared inside struct/class scope?

Tags: c++, c++11

With the following code

Header.h

```
namespace some_name {
    struct foo {
        // using alias
        using MyMap = std::map<double, some_class* const>;
        MyMap* GetMap();
        MyMap* map_;
    }
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

// using declaration
using some_name::foo;

MyMap* foo::GetMap(){
    ...
    return map_;
}
```

When I compile I get a compiler error that states:

> error: ‘MyMap’ does not name a type
>
> MyMap* foo::GetMap() {
>
> ^

However if I define `GetMap()` in place in the header file everything works fine but if I move it to source file I get that error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Using only works for namespaces, not for structs.

Comment: @BaummitAugen [Erm what?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5516cd1c40886d9b)

Comment: @Borgleader Not what I meant, but I admit I phrased that poorly. I meant to say that `using` cannot pull names from a `struct` to a namespace.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ok that makes sense, but I never would have guessed that meaning from your previous statement.

Comment: @Borgleader Yeah, I can see why. Sometimes my brain can't English. XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
using some_name::foo;
```

In your code just imports the name `foo` into the current scope.  That means that any time the compiler see's the unqualified name `foo` it will know you are using `some_name::foo`.

This will not help you with `MyMap` though.  `MyMap` is scoped by `foo` so in order to access you still need to use `foo::` like

```
foo::MyMap* foo::GetMap()
```

Another option would be to add another using statement to bring in `MyMap` but this will pollute the scope with that name so you may not want to do that.  If you do then you can use

```
// using declaration
using some_name::foo;
using MyMap = some_name::foo::MyMap;

MyMap* foo::GetMap(){
    ...
    return map_;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- `foo::MyMap*`
- `auto foo::GetMap()->MyMap*` (trailing return types) (since `c++11`)

---

you can only access `foo::MyMap` inside `struct foo`'s scope

the second version work without qualified because the `->MyMap*` part is consider inside the function's scope

---

Comment: It's probably worth qualifying your answer with an explanation about trailing return types

Comment: I selected the other answer b/c it was first and has more votes but I appreciate you pointing out the trailing return type option.

Comment: @jterm thank for the comment :) by the way, it is first because it have more votes. (and my answer is in fact a little fast)